# How do I put next and previous links in a header partial in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a bunch of records that each have individual detail pages, and I have simple next/previous links on my show.html.erb page that work well for cycling between the next and previous page. For example:

```
<%= link_to "&larr; Previous".html_safe,  @artwork.previous if @artwork.previous.present? %>
<%= link_to "Next &rarr;".html_safe, @artwork.next if @artwork.next.present? %>
```

artworks.rb:

```
  def previous
    Artwork.where(["id < ?", id]).order('rating DESC').last
  end

  def next
    Artwork.where(["id > ?", id]).first
  end
```

artworks_controller.rb

```
class ArtworksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_artwork, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :create, :update, :destroy, :admin]

  # GET /artworks
  # GET /artworks.json
  def index
    if params[:tag]
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end
  end

  def tagged
    if params[:tag].present? 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else 
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end  
  end

  def series
    if params[:series].present? 
      @artworks = Artwork.tagged_with(params[:series])
    else 
      @artworks = Artwork.all
    end  
  end

  def admin
    @artworks = Artwork.all
  end

  # GET /artworks/1
  # GET /artworks/1.json
  def show
    @artwork = Artwork.friendly.find(params[:id])
    if request.path != artwork_path(@artwork)
      redirect_to @artwork, status: :moved_permanently
    end
  end

  # GET /artworks/new
  def new
    @artwork = Artwork.new
  end

  # GET /artworks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /artworks
  # POST /artworks.json
  def create
    @artwork = Artwork.new( artwork_params )

    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.save
        format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'Artwork was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1
  # PATCH/PUT /artworks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @artwork.update(artwork_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'Artwork was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @artwork }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @artwork.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /artworks/1
  # DELETE /artworks/1.json
  def destroy
    @artwork.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @artwork, notice: 'Artwork was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

...(private params here)
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<div id="artworks" class="transitions-enabled">
      <% @artworks.each do |artwork| %>
        <div class="box">
        <%= link_to image_tag(artwork.image.url(:medium)), artwork %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
</div>
```

That's all good, but I want those links to appear within my _header.html.erb partial. I've tried copy/pasting them into there, but I get an error telling me there's a redirect loop. How would I get these links to work in the header? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see how information in your view could cause a redirect loop. That sounds like a controller problem. Is this the minimum code needed to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I added my controller code to the question.

Comment: Do you know the contents of `request.path`? I'd suspect the problem is `if request.path != artwork_path(@artwork)`.

Comment: Yes! You were right. When I comment out the lines `if request.path != artwork_path(@artwork)` it works just fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Argh. Now I'm getting a "NoMethodError in Artworks#index" error on the homepage saying "undefined method `previous' for nil:NilClass". But the previous method is defined in my model. How come it isn't working?

Comment: That's because your `index` action has `@artworks` defined, not `@artwork` like you expect in your next and previous links.

Comment: Okay, I think that make sense to me. I added the homepage code to my post. The behavior I'm trying to get is to have the next/prev links show up in the header on the show pages, but then don't show up on any other pages. Hence my `if @artwork.previous.present? ` statements. I modified this to say `<% if @artwork.previous.present? %>
      <%= link_to "&larr; Previous".html_safe, @artwork.previous %>
      <% end %>`. Is there something I could put in an `<% else %>` to make this work as intended? Or how do I get the next/prev links to look for the right thing? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I ask [another question which was more clear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28776463/how-to-get-prev-next-links-working-in-a-ror-header) which got me the answer I need. Thanks @ptd for your help!